# polymer 2 capybara not working

Tags: ruby, capybara, polymer-2.x

I am creating and app with polymer 1 and all works fine, but I start another personal app and I want to learn Polymer 2, but I have one very important problem
Testing the app with capybara in ruby and the behavior test is not working because with polymer 2 seems that not load the files js and css like bootstrap or similar files I load
The problem seems that capybara can't access to polymer, because if I put the code in the normal html file it is viewed fine in the save_screenshot of my test and capybara works well, but if I put it in the polymer 2 template, capybara not detect anything and seems that the page not load assets correctly

Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've correctly configured Capybara to use a JS capable driver (since it works when inline in the page for you) then it sounds like you have a JS error in your main JS file that is preventing some of the JS code from running.  Check your developer console in dev for any JS errors and fix them.  Another possibility is that you're using Poltergeist or capybara-webkit and are using JS features/methods from ES5.1+, in your main JS file, which aren't supported by those drivers.